# Can XML have a tag within text?

Tags: xml

Is the following file valid XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <body>Don't forget <i>me</i> this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

You can see that `<body>` has text content, which has another tag `<i>` inside of it.

Comment: yep thats totally legal. look at xhtml!

Answer (score 0):

It is legal. This is what mix-content aspect of XML is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, XML elements can have [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content).

This is true by default.

If you would like to declare what type of content your `<body>` tag can accept, there is a specific declaration format to allow mixed content.  In this case, to allow `<i>` tags within the `<body>` tag, declare:

```
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA|i)*>
```

Think of `#PCDATA` as meaning "any string of characters".  `(#PCDATA|i)*` is like a regex saying "You can have any string of characters, or an `<i>` tag, 0 or more times.